# tkinter: mainloop() opens root window twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

OS: Windows 10
Python 3.7, Jupyter notebook

I have a very simple script that opens a tkinter window with a single button that closes the window:

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("1000x600")
        quit_button = tk.Button(self.root,
                               text = 'root quit',
                               command=self.quit)
        quit_button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()
app = App()
```

If I run this code, a window opens up, and I can close it using the 'root quit' button.  If however, I comment out "self.root.mainloop," run the code, then uncomment "self.root.mainloop" and run the code again two windows open.

Why is this?!

Thanks

Comment: First we need to see the error and 2nd we need to see the code that creates the error. What you have shown now does not produce an error.

Comment: The kind of behavior you are describing is not reproducible. Please let us know what version of Python you are using and OS version. Also are you using an IDE like Eclipse/PyCharm or are you using python's default IDLE? Even using your example I am unable to produce 2 windows after fixing the error.

Comment: Are you running it in an interactive shell? If so some memory gets retained depending on how deep the error goes.

Comment: On your updated question I see `jupyter notebook` and instantly think thats where your problem is.